# How to tell if my neural network is crashing due to memory errors?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to calibrate my expectations around a single laptop's ability to train a neural network.  I am using tensorflow and keras and after about say 10 minutes, it crashes. I've seen `killsignal 9 exit code 137`, and I'm wondering if this is due to insufficient memory? Other times, when one-hot encoding using `np_utils.to_categorical()` I've seen the words `memoryerror` in the console, and that's it and my script crashes.  This is just trying to transform the outputs into what a neural net expects before it even runs.
I have 6400 inputs and 1500 outputs and a small hidden layer of 100 nodes. Batch size 128. 
That's it.  It's not even deep.  It crashes whether using an nvidia gpu or a 4 core cpu.  For you pros, is my network too big to train on my system (i7 4 cores, 16gb ram, nvidia GT 750m , compute capability 3.0).  Is my neural network considered a large one? I have 3 million samples, btw.

1) How do I estimate the amount of memory required for my network?  Is it `6400 (# inputs) * 1500 (#outputs) * 4 bytes (per parameter) = 38.4 gb`? Can I see how much memory is being used in real time on a mac somewhere?  I've used activity monitor and the memory pressure gauge is normal.
2) GPUs typically are maxing out at 8gb-12gb of RAM, whereas CPUs on desktops could easily have 64 gb.  So if the memory requirements of my network exceed 8gb of RAM, would it be impossible to train on a single GPU?
3) what is the difference, especially memory wise, between batch_size and batch_training?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the "3 million samples". Why not splitting it in smaller batches, such as "100.000 samples" for instance, and even though, when using the `fit`, still pass a small `batch_size`, 200, maybe.

Comment: Assessing memory requirements for a network is non-trivial. As a rough guide, look at your tensor shapes, look at variable types and multiply shape by memory requirement of the type and add everything up. For example, if you define a 6400 unit input layer, 100 hidden layer and 1500 output layer and lets say all of them are `tf.float64`, your minimum memory requirement (not taking into account the weights, biases and all the overhead) is going to be (64 * 6400 + 100 * 64 + 1500 * 64) * batch_size. If you are feeding all of your 3 million samples into this at once this comes out to some 1.4GB.

Comment: That said, there could be a lot of other things going on and seeing your model code might help.

Comment: Hi, could you go over your calculation in more detail?  I must have issues converting the bits to GB.  Most batch sizes are something like only 128, but you are saying that even if I set the batch size to 3,000,000 the total memory is 1.4 gb, which a very small amount of memory that any laptop should be able to handle.

Comment: From my calculation, you will use `6400 * 100 + 100 * 1500 = 790000 * 4 = 3160000 / 1000000 = 3.16` MBs per sample (not considering biases, but that will be negligible). I think your GPU memory is 2 GB. That means you can fit at most 590 samples per batch. Is your batch size larger than this? Do you also have validation? If yes, are you computing it inside `fit` or inside some callback? If yes, you have to add validation batch size to the 590 samples as well. Also from what you describe, you are running out of CPU RAM (maybe). So probably you want to consider a chunk of samples at once.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a batch_size of 128. Why Does the size of the dataset matter (total # of examples,3 million in my case) if we are only loading 128 examples at a time? When I only use a random 300,000 sample from my three million original dataset, I can train longer.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation was correct with the multiplication, with the exception, that you are dealing with mega bytes and not giga bytes. The actual requirement is 6400*100*4 + 100*1500*4, which should ~4 MB if you use the default float32. You multiply the layer sizes of two subsequent layers together, because every neuron is connected to every neuron in the subsequent layer. Then the whole memory requirement is multiplied by the batch size. This is why convolutional layers are used to train deep networks.

For gpu I am using nvidia-smi to monitor the memory requirements on linux. A google search gave me this for mac: https://phvu.net/2015/03/30/nvidia-smi-on-macos/. If the memory requirements exceed the GPU memory you can not train it on the gpu. You could train it on a cpu, but that will take ages.

There are multiple ways to train with a large training set. Normally generator are used to train on batches. This means only loading the parts of the training set you actually need (https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-use-keras-with-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-memory).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So smaller batch_size doesn't eliminate the need for loading a larger-than-RAM dataset in chunks? Does the entire dataset get loaded regardless of my batch_size or something? If so how does batch_size help?

Comment: Depends on your algorithm. If you load the whole dataset beforehand it does not help. If you use a generator you normally only load the batch size of samples beforehand. Thereby it would help if you could post your training code.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the memory requirements for your neural network not only depends on the size of the network or the number of parameters itself. For calculating the memory foot print of the neural network, one document that I always go to is the [Stanford CS231n Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) course notes. Please take a look at the portion where they find the memory requirements for each and every layer of the network.

To add to that, batch size (the number of inputs per one batch) is a crucial factor in deciding the 'memory usage'. For example, in a newer NVIDIA P100 GPU, I can go as much as 2048 images per batch if I train a CIFAR10 model and less than 512 or 256 images if I train AlexNet on ImageNet dataset. The input size matters a lot, so does the batch size since the GPU memory need to account for the batch of inputs.

One way to test the batch size which works is to do `nvidia-smi` and see how much memory is used. Since doing it every now and then is boring, I usually do `watch nvidia-smi` in my Linux machine. In my MAC, I do not have a NVIDIA GPU installed so I seldom use these tricks. When I want to, I will write quick bash scripts like these:

```
while true; do nvidia-smi; sleep 0.5; clear; done
```

You can port install `watch` in Mac as well.

Also, two of my most favorite tools of all time are [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) and [dstat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dstat).

`htop` gives you a much better graphical interface to the famous `top` command in Linux. It gives you real-time information regarding your memory and processor usage, along with the different processes. If you give `sudo` access to `htop`, you can change the niceness and other parameters directly from the interface.

`dstat` gives you real time information about your I/O. In most cases, I will add two flags `-d` and `-n` to specify disk and network usage only.

Fortunately, `htop` can be brew installed on Mac by running:

```
brew install htop
```

`dstat` on the other hand is not directly available. Please look into `ifstat` or `iostat` for similar functionalities.

A screenshot of `htop` command in Mac.
[image]